# Чтение файла в структуру

Tags: c#, файлы, структуры

Всем привет. Интересует такой вопрос: как прочесть файл в структуру?
Искал везде, наткнулся на сериализацию, но толком ничего не понял. Кто может объяснить на популярном языке, как это делается?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не забудьте в C# структуре указать атрибут [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
Статический класс Marshal находится в

`using System.Runtime.InteropServices;`

Код:

```
try
        {
            //ДЛЯ ФАЙЛА
            //byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("myFile.dat");
            //ДЛЯ ТЕСТА
            byte[] bytes = new byte[5];

            MyStruct structure;
structure = (MyStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure( Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(bytes, 0), typeof(MyStruct));
//Здесь 1.ищем указатель на первый байт массива;2.получаем структуру нужного типа
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // В случае ошибки (несовпадения файла, его отсутствия, недоступности для чтения, превышения памяти, и т.п.
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct MyStruct
    {
        int val; //4 байта
        byte bt; 
    }
```

Comment: - `StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)` [устанавливается по умолчанию для](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.runtime.interopservices.layoutkind) `value types`.

- Для сериализации произвольных классов, когда нет изначального предположения об `interop'e` с `unmanaged` кодом этот атрибут является мусором и влияет на `backward compatibility`. То есть, грубо говоря, совместимость сериализованных версий одного и того же класса без `LayoutKind.Sequential` гарантируется рантаймом, однако, если вы добавите этот атрибут, а потом случайно уберете его, то эта гарантия будет потеряна.

Comment: - Для сериализации произвольных классов, когда нет изначального предположения об `interop'e` с `unmanaged` кодом или необходимости использовать `Native` режим сериализации, этот атрибут является мусором и влияет на `backward compatibility`. То есть, грубо говоря, совместимость сериализованных версий одного и того же класса без `LayoutKind.Sequential` гарантируется рантаймом, однако, если вы добавите этот атрибут, а потом случайно уберете его, то эта гарантия будет потеряна.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, Если бы я писал библиотеку для других, то конечно сделал все: посмотрел в инете, как ведет себя тот или иной атрибут и выбрал лучшие опции. Но я обычно пишу для своих программ и мне backward compatibility не грозит)) Вообще ответ на этот вопрос - это всего лишь (MyStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(bytes, 0), typeof(MyStruct));    Остальное - это пример для начинающего Sharp `a

Comment: @semenvx27 Ну я так, вдруг кто-нибудь прочитает и решит, что это - аксиома и нужно всегда так делать :) А знание про `PtrToStructure` действительно небесполезно.

Comment: Спасибо, помогли!

Answer (score 3):

Ну чтобы прочесть файл в структуру, надо чтобы файл был соответствующей структуры, т.е. имел определенный формат. А вот сериализация - это способ сохранить объект в файл для его последующего востановления, например так можно сохранить состояние графа (к примеру).
Для реализации сериализации и десериализации нам надо подключить:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary; // тут класс BinaryFormatter 
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.IO; // для работы с файлами
```

Класс реализующий сериализацию должен иметь атрибут Serializable, т.е. перед классом пропишите [Serializable]. Небольшой пример:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary; // тут класс BinaryFormatter 
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.IO; // для работы с файлами

namespace NewProg
{
   [Serializable]
   class Program
   {
     static void Main (string[] args)
     {
       Serial(); // сериализуем
       UnSerial(); //ансериализуем ))
     }
     static void Serial()
     {
       // будем сериализовать строки
       List<string> str = new List<string>();
       str.Add("запись 1");
       // можно еще добавить, но не будем
       FileStream serFile = new FileStream("наш файл.x", FileMode.Create,   FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
       BinaryFormatter ser = new BinaryFormatter();
       ser.Serialize(serFile, str); // сериализуем
       serFile.Close();
     }
     static void UnSerial()
     {
       // куда сохранять
       List<string> unstr = null;
       FileStream filik = new FileStream("наш файл.x", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
       BinaryFormatter binf = new BinaryFormatter();
       unstr = (List<string>)binf.Deserialize(filik);
       filik.Close();
       // далее проделываем все необходимые манипуляции
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Веселые у вас аббревиатуры :)

Comment: Спасибо большое! Сериализация прояснилась.
Но вот, как допустим считать файл в структуру..
Структура заголовка такова:

struct sFileHdr { // 77x4
    unsigned long int DW_01; // 0x00000100
    unsigned long int DW_02; // 0x00000400
    char Type[8];
    char SubType[16];
    unsigned long int DW_03; // 0x00000000
    unsigned long int ImgFSize;
    unsigned long int OrigFSize;
    unsigned long int FOffset;
    unsigned long int DW_04; // 0x00000000
    char OrigLongFName[256];
    long int arrInt64[179];
} FileHdr;

Как считать этот заголовок файла в структуру?

Comment: Используя `FileStream` и `BinaryReader`. Если формат файла предопределён, сериализация не поможет, т.к. сериализаторы сохраняют данные в своём формате.

Comment: А как тогда быть? Считывать каждый элемент структуры в файла, не вариант. Можно ли как-нибудь записать структуру без сериализации?